# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "nav2_map_server"

Tags: navigation, mobile-robot, colcon, autonomous-car, ros-humble

I am learning ROS 2 and trying to develop an agriculture autonomous robot package on ROS 2 Humble with Ubuntu 22.04. While building with colcon build, I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package):
By not providing "Findnav2_map_server.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this                                                                                                                    
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by                                                                                                                  
"nav2_map_server", but CMake did not find one.                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                          
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "nav2_map_server"                                                                                                                 
with any of the following names:                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                          
  nav2_map_serverConfig.cmake                                                                                                                                                             
  nav2_map_server-config.cmake                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                          
Add the installation prefix of "nav2_map_server" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or                                                                                                                  
set "nav2_map_server_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.                                                                                                               
If "nav2_map_server" provides a separate development package or SDK, be                                                                                                                   
sure it has been installed.
```

I have installed the navigation2 package based on [the official documentation](https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html#installation).

Below is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(aamr_pkg)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# Set the default path for finding dependencies
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/ros/humble/share)

# Set nav2_map_server_DIR
set(nav2_map_server_DIR /opt/ros/humble/share/nav2_map_server)

# Set nav2_recovery_behavior_DIR
set(nav2_recovery_behavior_DIR /opt/ros/humble/share/nav2_recovery_behavior)

add_executable(aamr_pkg src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(aamr_pkg
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(nav_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(action_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(cv_bridge REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_index_cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
find_package(gazebo_ros_pkgs REQUIRED)
find_package(robot_state_publisher REQUIRED)
find_package(ompl REQUIRED)
find_package(moveit REQUIRED)
#find_package(descartes REQUIRED)
find_package(trajectory_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(ros2_control REQUIRED)
find_package(robot_localization REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_map_server REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_controller REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_planner REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_behavior_tree REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_recovery_behavior REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_costmap_2d REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_core REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_util REQUIRED)
find_package(amcl REQUIRED)
find_package(fastcdr REQUIRED)
find_package(fastrtps REQUIRED)
find_package(performance_test REQUIRED)
find_package(msg_data_lib REQUIRED)
find_package(rmw_fastrtps_cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED)
find_package(opencv REQUIRED)
#find_package(third_party REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

Kindly help. I have been trying to solve it for one month; I have all the needed dependencies but am getting errors.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

It seems that you have not installed all the Nav2 packages. 1. Can you please execute `sudo apt install ros-humble-navigation2` and `sudo apt install ros-humble-nav2-bringup`, then try again? The `CMakeLists.txt` file looks strange. 2. Can you please tell us which node or launch file you are trying to execute?

Comment: You can install the specific package using `apt` as well `sudo apt install ros-humble-nav2-map-server`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply have not installed it or built it from source.

`sudo apt install ros-<version>-nav2-map-server`

That cmake error is just complaining generically that it cannot find the package. If you have installed it and still seeing that, you may not have sourced the workspace / installation of the ROS distribution where it is contained.